# Redirect to custom 404-page doesn't work on localhost (Apache)

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a `.htaccess`-file that has the directives as listed below. The first three lines are used to provide custom error pages for 403, 404 and 429.

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
ErrorDocument 403 /403.php
ErrorDocument 429 /429.php

DirectoryIndex maintenance.html index.php index.html index.htm home.html 
#Rewrite everything to https
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} != 'localhost'">
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</If>
<Else>
    # local configuration 
    # nothing special here...
</Else>
```

This works perfectly fine when I publish to my website. When trying to open a non-existing page such as `mysite.com/wrongpage.php` the custom 404.php page is showed.

But when I try to do the same thing on localhost when entering `localhost/wrongpage.php`. It simply shows the browsers default 404 message. The `404.php` page exists, but isn't used as expected.

I am not very good at how to work with the `.htaccess` file, but perhaps you can help me understand why it won't work on localhost?

Comment: How did you get on with this?

Answer (score 0):

This suggests you've not enabled `.htaccess` overrides on your local development server. `.htaccess` files are essentially disabled so the directives are not doing anything.

You need to set the `AllowOverride` directive in the appropriate `<Directory>` container in the server config (or `<VirtualHost>` container). By "appropriate" I mean the specific `<Directory>` container that targets your document root directory, not the entire server (which should remain `AllowOverride None`).

For example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    <Directory /var/www/html>
        Require all granted

        # Enable .htaccess overrides
        AllowOverride All

    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And restart Apache.

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowoverride